# Vista MVC no se renderiza en Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

tengo una vista que no se renderiza, si no que por el contrario, muestra los datos de un viewmodel que le estoy pasando a traves del controller para llenar un dropdownList.

Este es mi controller

```
        public ActionResult Inicio()
    {

        int KamId = 1;
        TW.Business.Kam.DatosKam ck = new DatosKam();
        VM_ComboClientesKam VM_cmbCliKam = ck.GetComboClientesKam(KamId);
        if (VM_cmbCliKam != null)
        {
            return Json(new { data = VM_cmbCliKam }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

aca la vista:

```html
@model TW.Model.Kam.ViewModels.VM_ComboClientesKam


<div id="InfoProceso" class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Cierre de Mes</h1>
        <p class="lead">Proceso de cierre de mes, permite ingresar informacion de asistencia, bonos y descuentos de los trabajadores TeamWork.</p>

        <p><a href="https://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Ver mas &raquo;</a></p>
</div>


<div id="SeleccionaCliente">
    <p class="lead">Seleccione un cliente para definir la plantilla a utilizar</p>

    <p>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCliente, new SelectList(Model.lstClientesKam, "ClienteId", "ClienteNombre"))
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

el viewmodel a traves del cual paso los datos es :

```
    public class VM_ComboClientesKam
{
    public IEnumerable<VM_ClientesViewModel> lstClientesKam { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCliente { get; set; }
}

public class VM_ClientesViewModel
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string ClienteNombre { get; set; }
}
```

Alguien le pasa esto?

Lo que me retorna la pagina, es un json con los datos del combobox.

```
{"data":{"lstClientesKam":[{"ClienteId":1,"ClienteNombre":"Artel S.A.I.C."},{"ClienteId":2,"ClienteNombre":"BCI CORREDORES DE SEGUROS S.A."},{"ClienteId":3,"ClienteNombre":"BCI SEGUROS VIDA S.A."}],"SelectedCliente":0}}
```

Comment: mira este workshop completo, te será de mucha utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Answer (score 0):

Me di cuenta que estaba haciendo algo mal.

Estaba respondiendo con un json:

```
return Json(new { data = VM_cmbCliKam }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Y no con una vista, como se esperaba.